# Python PYQT converting a file

Tags: python, pyqt

Trying to be the office hero(failing) and creating a gui which converts files in a directory.  I am close but need help passing a directory once a button is selected to the convertor..

```
def selectFile(self):


    self.listWidget.clear() # In case there are any existing elements in the list
    directory = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Pick a folder")


    for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
        if file_name.endswith(".csv"):
            self.listWidget.addItem(file_name)
            print (file_name)

def convertfile(self, directory):

    directoryPath = directory
#################
    #^^Directory from selection above to be put as directory for this convertor
###################

    print directoryPath, ':'

    # process all non-master CSVs
    for fileLocated in directoryPath:
        if fileLocated.endswith(".csv") and 'master' not in fileLocated.lower():

            csvFilename = fileLocated
            strippedFileName =  os.path.splitext(csvFilename)[0]
            wavFileName =  directoryPath  + strippedFileName + ".wav"

            print strippedFileName
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you add dir to your self something like this ?

```
class test(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        self.directory = None

    def selectFile(self):
        self.listWidget.clear() # In case there are any existing elements in the list
        directory = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Pick a folder")
        self.directory = directory

    def convertfile(self):
        directoryPath = self.directory
```